# Nodejs crypto aes-256-cbc: The argument 'encoding' is invalid for data of length 383. Received 'hex'

Tags: node.js, jwt, cryptojs

I am encrypting JWT tokens using crypto with Node.js. After a user logs in, I provide the encrypted tokens to the client. Then, whenever the client sends these encrypted tokens back to me along with a request, I decrypt them and continue with the process.

However, sometimes I encounter this error while decrypting the encrypted tokens:

[image]

The functions I use to encrypt and decrypt tokens are provided below. The error I mentioned above occurs in the decryptData function, which I handle in the catch block.

Here is the code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const key = crypto
   .createHash('sha512')
   .update(process.env.AES_SECRET_KEY)
   .digest('hex')
   .substring(0, 32)

const encryptionIV = crypto
   .createHash('sha512')
   .update(process.env.AES_SECRET_IV)
   .digest('hex')
   .substring(0, 16)

const method = 'aes-256-cbc'

// Encrypt data
exports.encryptData = (data) => {
   try {
      const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(method, key, encryptionIV)
      return Buffer.from(
         cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex')
      ).toString('base64') 
   } catch (error) {
    return undefined
   }
}

// Decrypt data
exports.decryptData = (encryptedData) => {
   try {
      const buff = Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'base64')
      const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(method, key, encryptionIV)
      return (
         decipher.update(buff.toString('utf8'), 'hex', 'utf8') +
         decipher.final('utf8')
      ) 
   } catch (error) {
      return undefined
   }
}
```

Comment: Hex encoded data has an even length, as each raw byte is mapped to two characters. With your problem, the data is 383 characters long according to the error message, so it is not valid hex data, which triggers the error. I cannot reproduce such an error with your code, s. online here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/XsH. It is possible that the data is corrupted during subsequent processing (e.g. during data transfer).

Comment: Therefore, you should post non-productive sample data: Log on both sides, the encrypting and decrypting side for a coherent encryption and decryption process: key, IV plaintext and ciphertext that leads to the problem. Maybe this data will allow further conclusions to be drawn.

Comment: Note that you encode the ciphertext twice, once hex, once Base64. This is unnecessary and inefficient. Remove one of the encodings (e.g. the more inefficient hex encoding). Regarding `AES_SECRET_IV`, bear in mind that the IV is *not* secret (so usually a random IV is generated during encryption and sent to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext to avoid the reuse of key/IV pairs).

Comment: @Topaco Thank you, the information you provided was really helpful, and I managed to solve the issue by changing the encryption algorithm. Right now, however, sometimes two equal signs are added to the end of the encrypted string and sometimes they are not. I'm investigating under which circumstances this occurs. Do you have any information about this?

Comment: This is most likely the [Base64 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding).